# textbox Empty validation

Tags: c#

I'm trying to validate a text box in a form to not having empty string if the user didn't entered anything in the text box, so if the text box was empty, the user has to enter a value ,and my code was like this, but it is not working

```
  public int TextBox_Validation(string sender)
  {


      try
      {

          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sender))
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value");
          }

      }
      catch
      {
          int num = int.Parse(sender);
          return 0;

      }
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: I don't see anything that can throw an exception in your `try` block so your `catch` block is pretty much useless.

Comment: also, i might help a bit, if we know what platform you are using---silverlight, wpf, asp.net, winforms, console, etc.

Comment: at what point of time(event) is this method being called??...A more detailed code would be helpful...May be this method is correct and the fault lies in what value you are passing to the method...

Comment: are you writing asp.net? silverlight? (etc.)

Comment: @Susan, where is TextBox_Validation being called?

Comment: @Susan, I notice you're an unregistered user, which means that when your cookies expire, you won't be able to accept or upvote for this question. I suggest you do so as soon as one or more of the answers have helped you! :-) I also suggest you register your account so you aren't constantly creating unregistered usernames.

Answer (score 2):

Sender generally refers to just the sending object, so check that you are sending the text of the textbox and not a reference to the textbox.

Also, you are always returning zero. Change your code to the following. You will return a `1` if the validation passes and `0` if it fails. Incidentally, you should be using a `boolean` instead of an `int`. I commented out a line below because it isn't doing anything constructive in this situation:

```
try
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sender))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value");
        return 0;
    }
}
catch
{
    //int num = int.Parse(sender);
    return 0;
}
return 1;
```

I recommend your change your method to the below. You don't need your `try {} catch {}` because `isNullOrEmpty` covers the lone potential null issue:

```
bool ValidateText(string Text)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't look like an event handler here, so sender can be whatever @susan wants

Comment: @Muad, I know. It was a warning because the name raises red flags in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool TextBox_Validation(string sender) {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sender);
}

        if(TextBox_Validation(textbox1.Value)) {
             //OK
         } else { 
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value");
             //ETC
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't throwing an exception so you won't make it into the catch block.

```
public int TextBox_Validation(string value)
{
    int integer = 0;

    if( string.IsNullOrEmpty( value ) )
    {
        MessageBox.Show( "Please enter a value" );    
    }
    else
    {
        int.TryParse( value, out integer );
    }

    return integer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try-catch blocks are useless, method should return bool and should not show any messages. It is a bad practice to do not related things in a single method (show messages, return some meaningless numbers, etc). If it is validating method, it should tell you only one thing - whether passed string is valid or not (just a single bool in your case), that's all. You should consider showing messages to user in another method. And one more thing - depending on technology you are using, it may have better validation support (validation in WF, validation rules in WPF, etc), use them, instead of handling some input events

Answer (score 1):

You're algorithm is incorrect. The `catch` block is used to catch errors that occur within the preceeding `try` block. In this case, I don't see a runtime error occurring so there probably is no need to a try/catch block, but I'll leave in for example sake. Also, your function doesn't provide a way for the program to know if it was empty or not. You could return 0 if it is empty or 1 if not. or return boolean true or false. Maybe a function like this would be better:

```
  public bool TextBox_Validation(string sender)
  {
      try
      {

          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sender))
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value");
              return false;
          }
          else
              return true;

      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
          return false;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this instead

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTextBox.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Value Please.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);           
    }
    else
    {
//whatever u need to do
    }
```